# Mais ou menos um Select em array

Tags: php, array

Boa noite, tenho dois Arrays:

```
$array1 = ( 

[0] => Array ("Nome":"Rodrigo","CPF":"123456789-00","Cargo":"Abestado")
[1] => Array ("Nome":"Maria","CPF":"987654321-00","Cargo":"Abestada")

$array2 = ( 

[0] => Array ("CPF":"123456789-00","Titulo de Eleitor":"456789123")
[1] => Array ("CPF":"987654321-00","Titulo de Eleitor":"987564123")
```

Nestes arrays eu tenho muitos registros.
O que quero saber é se da pra fazer uma consulta pelo CPF entre os arrays. Então eu procuro CPF do $array1 = CPF do $array2.
Quando o resultado for TRUE, quero que seja imbutido no $array3 os dados que diferem entres os arrays assim:

```
$array3 = ( 

[0] => Array ("Nome":"Rodrigo","CPF":"123456789-00","Cargo":"Abestado","Titulo de Eleitor":"987564123")
[1] => Array ("Nome":"Maria","CPF":"987654321-00","Cargo":"Abestada","Titulo de Eleitor":"987564123")
```

Isso é possível?

Desde já agradeço pela ajuda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma outra forma que preza mais pela performance é:

- Criar um array auxiliar com base no `array2` que utilize o `cpf` como chave para que a pesquisa seja feita em tempo costante, O(1).
- Percorrer cada elemento do `array1` e se encontrar o `cpf` no `array2` adiciona a junção dos dois arrays ao array final através da função [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-merge.php)

Implementação:

```
$arrayChaves = Array(); //array com cpfs como chaves
foreach($array2 as $valor){
    $chave = $valor["CPF"];
    $arrayChaves[$chave] = $valor;
    unset($arrayChaves[$chave]["CPF"]); //retirar cpf dos valores parar ficar só como chave
}

$arrayFinal = Array();
foreach($array1 as $pessoa){
    $cpfPessoa = $pessoa["CPF"];
    if (isset($arrayChaves[$cpfPessoa])){ //se o cpf existe no arrayChaves
        //adiciona a junção dos dois arrays
        $arrayFinal[] = array_merge($pessoa, $arrayChaves[$cpfPessoa]);
    }
}
```

[Veja este exemplo a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/Bwl7Pp)

Neste exemplo o resultado foi construido num outro array que chamei de `$arrayFinal`. Se quiser também pode alterar o `$array1` que tem diretamente, reescrevendo um pouco um ultimo `for`:

```
foreach($array1 as $pos => $pessoa){ //agora com chave e valor
    $cpfPessoa = $pessoa["CPF"];
    if (isset($arrayChaves[$cpfPessoa])){ //se o cpf existe no arrayChaves
        //a modificação é feita pelo array1 e a sua chave
        $array1[$pos] = array_merge($pessoa, $arrayChaves[$cpfPessoa]);
    }
}
```

[Veja também este exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/eEDT2L)

Comment: Ótima resposta a sua! Dei uma melhorada na performance do meu código graças a sua resposta.  =)

Comment: @AndreiCoelho Ainda bem :). De facto agora ficou bem melhor, guardando previamente a transformação em colunas para não ter que a fazer em cada passo.

Comment: Perfeito Isac! Exatamente isso!

Comment: Simplesmente perfect man. Obrigado Isac

Comment: Andrei, só infelizmente não se pode dar um check nas duas respostas. Pois esta explicito que a resposta do Isac foi uma melhora da sua. Obrigado pelo seu tempo.

Comment: @RodrigoPereiradeFreitas tranquilo! Também achei a resposta do Isac melhor. =)

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o **[array_column](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-column.php)** para pegar todos os valores de um array de uma chave específica junto com o `array_search` para saber se existe o valor pesquisado. E depois inserir no novo array:

```
    $array1 =   array( 
        array ("Nome" => "Rodrigo","CPF" => "123456789-00","Cargo"=>"Abestado"),
        array("Nome" => "Andrei","CPF" => "12312313-00","Cargo"=>"Abestado em Programação")
    );
    $array2 =array(array ("CPF"=>"123456789-00","Titulo de Eleitor"=>"456789123")) ;

    $array3 = array();

    $colunas = array_column($array2, 'CPF');

    foreach($array1 as $pessoas){
        if(($key = array_search($pessoas['CPF'],$colunas)) !== false)
            $array3[] = array(
                "Nome" => $pessoas['Nome'], 
                "CPF" => $pessoas['CPF'], 
                "Cargo" => $pessoas['Cargo'],
                "Titulo de Eleitor" =>  $array2[$key]['Titulo de Eleitor']
            );

    }

    print_r($array3);
```

Saída será:

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [Nome] => Rodrigo [CPF] => 123456789-00 [Cargo]
>   => Abestado [Titulo de Eleitor] => 456789123 ) )

Comment: Agradeço a ajuda man

Comment: @RodrigoPereiradeFreitas estamos ai pra isso. =) Abraço.

Answer (score 0):

Editado:

> Sem firulas:
>
> ```
> $array3 = array_replace_recursive($array1,$array2);
> ```

Comment: João, boa noite. Não testei seu código e por isso peço desculpas. Usei a resposta do Isac que realmente aumentou o desempenho do código. ficou muito rapido e o resultado foi acima do esperado. Vou estudar seu código pois me pareceu muito bom também ok. abraço